# Using scholar.py with sqlite database to extract information

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to use Scholar.py to retrieve bib text and citation count .
I have a sqlite database of author names.
I am not sure how can I use scholar.py with my database and extract information for each author.

Comment: What is the code that you have written so far?